# PHP preg_replace not removing quotes as expected

Tags: php

```
$string = '""mystring"":""""';

$result = preg_replace('/""/', '"', $string);
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
"mystring":""
```

But instead it is

```
""mystring":"""
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: why don't you use `str_replace`? you don't need a regex here

Comment: [norepro](https://3v4l.org/1iKBJ)

Comment: it is working: https://3v4l.org/HLcWV